# Want to open landscape links inside my android webview website by single click instead of two clicks

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, screen-orientation

I am trying to make an android app from my website using webview such that I want a certain links in my website to open in landscape mode and others in portrait mode inside my webview. For this purpose, I have implemented below code inside the overridden function shouldOverrideUrlLoading which does the work, but not up to the mark. What this code does is, on clicking the landscape links the first time, it changes orientation of the present page to landscape mode but does not go to the website link and if I click it a second time when the current page is already in landscape mode, then it goes to the website link in landscape mode. This does the work, but it is very irritating because the link positions get changed in landscape mode and user will have to again search the link by scrolling and if the user clicks a portrait mode link during the second time, the present page turns to portrait mode but does not go to the website link. In short, the activity restarts due to orientation change, but the weird thing is this happens irrespective of the order of loadUrl and setRequestedOrientation functions and makes no difference on placing sleep ( for say 5 seconds ) before or after setRequestedOrientation, in either cases it sleeps ( for say 5 seconds ) first and then changes the orientation on first click and on second click, it sleeps first ( for say 5 seconds ) and then loads the url link and I am unable to understand the reason behind this strange behaviour ( Same feeling which quantum mechanics scientists experience ). I have tried everything like giving below code in AndroidManifest file :

```
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

And also tried overriding below functions in MainActivity file :

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mywebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mywebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Experts please help in resolving this orientation change on first click only.

```
 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


              view.loadUrl(url);


              /*  try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

                if(url.contains("<<some keywords>>")){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                }
                else{
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }



        return true;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried onPageFinished method ? try to set orientation in this method

Comment: Yes @Basiljose, I have tried to set orientation inside onPageFinished as well as onLoadResources, but in both of those cases, it remains on the current page only and just rotates to landscape mode and then again to portrait mode, no matter how many times you click on link.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code ! i have implemented `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`,`onPageStarted` ,`onPageFinished` .Screen Orientation is changed in `onPageStarted` if any condition satisfy .

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private WebView mywebView;
private ProgressBar myprogressBar;
private static final String TAG = "WebViewActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    myprogressBar = findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);
    myprogressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mywebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    mywebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    mywebView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");


}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mywebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mywebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: loading ");
        myprogressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPageStarted: started");
        myprogressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        /*
            here you have to include the your keywords instead of tags [hardcoded string]
         */
        if (url.contains("tags")) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        myprogressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished: finished");
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Basiljose, your code works really well but only for the first time for each link. If I close and open my app, it is back to pavilion and remains on same current website as earlier and keeps on changing orientations in a weird way. If I clear the app data, then again it works as expected but again only for the first time for each link. But still, this was a good effort, I must say, and thanks for your time.

Comment: Also, one more issue happening with this code is that, after changing to landscape mode, the right part of the screen from the middle gets trimmed off into complete black for a few seconds and then again gets back to normal landscape. This happens at an interval of 30 to 60 seconds after changing to landscape mode.

Comment: can you share the code you have done [update question] , include the url too , so i can help you more

Comment: Sorry, cannot share the url due to company policies. But I can inform you that we have videos in landscape links.

Comment: okay that fine , let me try any video listing url and check whether the issue persists